# g++ goes too far when compiling

Tags: c++, templates, g++, static-compilation

I'm trying to implement very simple single inheritance stack tracing in C++ using a recursive template:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class C> struct MakeAlias : C{ typedef C Base; };
class StackTrace{
      public:
      static int var;
      virtual ~StackTrace() {}
      template <class T> void printStackTrace(T* c){
          if(typeid(T)==typeid(StackTrace))return; 
          cout << typeid(T).name() << "." << endl;
          class T::Base *V;
          printStackTrace(V);
     }
};
class A : public MakeAlias<StackTrace>{
};
class B : public MakeAlias<A>{
};
class C : public MakeAlias<B>{
    public:
    void hello(){
        cout << "hello from ";
        StackTrace::printStackTrace(this);
        cout << endl;
    }

};
int main(){
    C c;
    c.hello();
}
```

Everything should be okay, but when I try to compile it g++ ignores the
**if(typeid(T)==typeid(StackTrace))return;** line and returns the following error:

```
st.cpp: In member function `void StackTrace::printStackTrace(T*) [with T = StackTrace]':
st.cpp:13:   instantiated from `void StackTrace::printStackTrace(T*) [with T = A]'
st.cpp:13:   instantiated from `void StackTrace::printStackTrace(T*) [with T = B]'
st.cpp:13:   instantiated from `void StackTrace::printStackTrace(T*) [with T = C]'
st.cpp:24:   instantiated from here
st.cpp:12: error: no type named `Base' in `class StackTrace'
st.cpp:13: error: no type named `Base' in `class StackTrace'
```

It tries to call C::Base::Base::Base::Base /StackTrace::Base/ class, which will never be called during runtime. Even if I put **return** statement immediately after  printStackTrace declaration, the same error is evaluated. Why the scope and the member functions are not checked dynamically and why the compiler ignores the **return**?

Comment: Because templates are a purely compile-time construct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Templates are a purely compile-time construct. They simply instruct the compiler to generate classes or functions, which are then compiled normally (so they must be syntactically valid, except for [some special exceptions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SFINAE)).

You can get around this by providing an overload of `printStackTrace`:

```
template <class T>
void printStackTrace(T *c)
{
  cout << typeid(T).name() << "." << endl;
  typename T::Base *V;
  printStackTrace(V);
}

void printStackTrace(StackTrace *c)
{
  cout << typeid(StackTrace).name() << "." << endl;
}
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/hvPzCF)

Answer (score 1):

Regardless if you return early, the compiler will expand the line

```
class T::Base *V;
```

recursively. If you want to stop the compiler from expanding templates forever (or until the compiler blows some internal limit, whichever comes first :-)) you need to do the dispatching at compile time. perhaps something like this will do the trick. Change your printStackTrace function to

```
template <class T>
void printStackTrace(T* c) {
    printStackTraceImpl(c, std::is_same<T, StackTrace>);
}

template <class T>
void printStackTraceImpl(T* c, std::true_type) { 
      cout << typeid(T).name() << "." << endl;
      class T::Base *V;
      printStackTrace(V);
}

template <class T>
void printStackTraceImpl(T* c, std::false_type) { 
    // do nothing.
}
```

Edit: or as suggested elsewhere, provide an overload for type StackTrace. That's actually much cleaner than my untested code :-)

Comment: Why all the `std::conditional`? If you have C++11 anyway, just use `std::is_same`.

Comment: Very true. Updating. Dunno why I reached for the heavy guns so quickly, lol.